# How to continue training an exported JSON LSTM model to improve accuracy using Brain.js?

Tags: node.js, google-colaboratory, lstm, brain.js, resuming-training

I'm working on an exciting project where I'm using Brain.js to train a text classification model based on an LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) network. So far, I've successfully trained the model and exported it in JSON format. However, I'm facing a challenge: I want to find a way to continue training the exported model to improve its accuracy.

I've researched different approaches and reviewed various answers provided on Stack Overflow regarding this topic. Some suggestions mention using the options "keepNetworkIntact: true" or "reinforce: true" when loading the exported model in Brain.js, hoping that they would allow for further training without losing the existing network structure or learning capacity.